# Duplicate a list with linked input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm a pretty noob in javascript. I'm trying to duplicate a list which has input field for each option. So far it's working, though, the duplicated list don't show the associated input fields. Also I would want to make a sum of every field that has a data.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn-copy").click(function() {
    var target = $(this).closest(".revenus");
    target.clone(true, true).appendTo(target.parent());
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  toggleFields();
  $("#revenu-type").change(function() {
    toggleFields();
    toggleFields2();
  });

});

function toggleFields() {
  if ($("#revenu-type").val() === "option-1")
    $("#option-a").show();
  else
    $("#option-a").hide();
  if ($("#revenu-type").val() === "option-2")
    $("#option-b").show();
  else
    $("#option-b").hide();
  if ($("#revenu-type").val() === "option-3")
    $("#option-c").show();
  else
    $("#option-c").hide();
  if ($("#revenu-type").val() === "option-4")
    $("#option-d").show();
  else
    $("#option-d").hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="revenus">
  <p>Choose type</p>
  <p>revenue:
    <select id="revenu-type" name="dbType">
      <option>Ajouter un autre revenu</option>
      <option value="option-1">Revenu 1</option>
      <option value="option-2">Revenu 2</option>
      <option value="option-3">Revenu 3</option>
      <option value="option-4">Revenu 4</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <div id="option-a" style="display: flex;">
    <p>Option 1 - a
      <input type="text" name="num-child" />
    </p>
    <p>Option 1 - b
      <input type="text" name="price-1" />
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="option-b">
    <p>Option 2
      <input type="text" name="price-2" />
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="option-c">
    <p>Option 3
      <input type="text" name="price-3" />
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="option-d">
    <p>Option 4
      <input type="text" name="price-4" />
    </p>
  </div>
  <p align="left">
    <input type="button" value="add" id="btn-copy" />
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Using `id`s will prevent your scripts to work properly. Remember `id`s must be unique. After you clone the content, all ids will be duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is in your `toggleFields` - when you use

```
$("#option-a")...
```

it will only find the first one as IDs must be unique.

So the first thing to do is change all the `id=` to `class=` (and change corresponding selectors).

You need to find the one that's related to the current `revenu-type` inside the current `.revenus`.  You can do that by passing `this` to `toggleFields` - with a slight change from `this` to `$(this).closest(".revenus")` to pass in the outer wrapper.

From there, you can use:

```
wrapper.find(".option-a")...
```

to get the item within the wrapper.

The btn-copy click events gets cloned, so while this should use a class and event delegation `$("document").on("click", ".btn-copy" ...` it will still work with the clone including events.

Without changing too much of your existing code (eg using `.toggle(bool)` instead of `if (bool) ..show else ..hide`), this gives:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn-copy").click(function() {
    var target = $(this).closest(".revenus");
    target.clone(true, true).appendTo(target.parent());
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  toggleFields($(".revenus").first());
  $(".revenu-type").change(function() {
    toggleFields($(this).closest(".revenus"));
    //toggleFields2();
  });

});

function toggleFields(wrapper) {
  if (wrapper.find(".revenu-type").val() === "option-1")
    wrapper.find(".option-a").show();
  else
    wrapper.find(".option-a").hide();
  if (wrapper.find(".revenu-type").val() === "option-2")
    wrapper.find(".option-b").show();
  else
    wrapper.find(".option-b").hide();
  if (wrapper.find(".revenu-type").val() === "option-3")
    wrapper.find(".option-c").show();
  else
    wrapper.find(".option-c").hide();
  if (wrapper.find(".revenu-type").val() === "option-4")
    wrapper.find(".option-d").show();
  else
    wrapper.find(".option-d").hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="revenus">
  <p>Choose type</p>
  <p>revenue:
    <select class="revenu-type" name="dbType">
      <option>Ajouter un autre revenu</option>
      <option value="option-1">Revenu 1</option>
      <option value="option-2">Revenu 2</option>
      <option value="option-3">Revenu 3</option>
      <option value="option-4">Revenu 4</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <div class="option-a" style="display: flex;">
    <p>
      Option 1 - a
      <input type="text" name="num-child" />
    </p>
    <p>
      Option 1 - b
      <input type="text" name="price-1" />
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="option-b">
    <p>
      Option 2
      <input type="text" name="price-2" />
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="option-c">
    <p>
      Option 3
      <input type="text" name="price-3" />
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="option-d">
    <p>
      Option 4
      <input type="text" name="price-4" />
    </p>
  </div>
  <p align="left">
    <input type="button" value="add" id="btn-copy" />
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Note [`$(selector)`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1) has a second optional context parameter. So all your `find`s can be shortened to: `$(selector, wrapper)`. As a matter of fact, it will still work with duplicate ids if you provide context param, as jQuery won't look outside of the context element. It's wrong, but it works. If it didn't oh so many sites would break, unfortunately :). Happy coding!

Comment: @tao yes, I went with `wrapper.find` as it's generally clearer/easier to read than `$(selector, wrapper)`.  Good point about `$("#id", wrapper)` and a good trick to know about, but probably not good practice :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers! I spent too much time trying to solve this. Also, if you may, I have another question. Is there a way to remove the previous choosen option in the right next one after duplicating it. I mean, if I choose for example, revenu 3 and then click on add, I will only find Revenue 1, 2 and 4 and so on?

Comment: If this answers you original question, please accept it.  I recommend you ask another SO question for your follow up question, you'll more likely get a/multiple responses from a new question than from a comment on an answered question.

Comment: Alright, I will do that, thank you for your advice.